# check box is not align left

Tags: html, thymeleaf

In my spring app I use thymeleaf and want check box to be align left.
In my template:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 th:text="*{title}"/>
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/user}">
        <table cellspacing="10">               
            <tr align="left">
                <td align="right"><label for="active">Active</label></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="checkbox" align="left" placeholder="active" id="active"
                                        th:field="*{active}"
                                        th:readonly="${isView}"/></td>
            </tr>                
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="created" th:field="*{created}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input th:type="${isView} ? hidden : submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see I use `align=left` but it's not help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
    width: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` attribute in such conditions:

```
<td colspan="2">
<label for="active">Active</label>
<input type="checkbox" align="left" placeholder="active" id="active" th:field="*{active}" th:readonly="${isView}"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Now label in over checkbox. It's not help